# selenium: find the right button but fail to click by using className

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I try to find the button by using two way. The first by the xpath directly which is working. But the second way is not working. after using the click() function nothing happen and no error.

First way:

```
By.xpath(".//*[@id='app:viewAppInsideConfirm:confirmInside:j_id300']").click()
```

Second way:

```
By.className("iceCmdBtn").click()
```

html:

```
<input id="app:viewAppInsideConfirm:confirmInside:j_id300" class="iceCmdBtn" type="submit" value=" Yes " onfocus="setFocus(this.id);" onclick="parent.JSsessionTimeOut.resetSessionTimeout();iceSubmit(form,this,event);return false;" onblur="setFocus('');" name="app:viewAppInsideConfirm:confirmInside:j_id300"></input>
```

BTW:

I try to use xpath to find different items, I got:

Use 'sumbit' as key word can find it, but same as the  By.className("iceCmdBtn") Find but with click() no action...

```
  String xpathLocater = ".//*[@type='submit']"; 
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLocater)).click();
```

For the ' Yes ' , I got error to find the element...

String xpathLocater = ".//*[@value=' Yes ']";
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLocater)).click();

Guys!!!

It have another button:

So I guess I need use FindElements

Comment: If it works by xpath, why not just use xpath?

Comment: because  the id will change, this is dynamic

Comment: Which find method on the Driver you are using? `FindElement` or `FindElements`? If you are using the first method the driver stops on the first found element. Maybe `Driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("iceCmdBtn")).First(e => e.Displayed).Click()` could help? (C# syntax by the way)

Comment: Please check how many elements are attached to classname `iceCmdBtn`. Might be that class being used by more than 1 element.

Comment: I checked, only have one item for that class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dynamic part of the `id` is `300` in your example, you can apply a partial check using [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with):

```
By.xpath(".//input[starts-with(@id, 'app:viewAppInsideConfirm:confirmInside:') and @class='iceCmdBtn']").click()
```

Comment: @Chen okay, updated the xpath adding `input` instead of `*` and checking the class. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks~ works with String xpathLocater = "//input[starts-with(@id,'app:viewAppInsideConfirm:confirmInside:j_id')]";